# Adding element to div dynamically doesn't get parsed

Tags: jquery, html, css, insertafter

I have a div that has multiple child divs, or panels, that on page load, have styles appended to them placing them in the correct way on the page. I have a button that adds a new panel, but that panel doesn't get the necessary styles added to it. (The method is the jQuery `insertAfter` function). I am using the Syrena Admin template, so I do not know the function to call to re-parse the elements. Is there a way to reload the div as if the page was reloading? In other words is there a way to reload only part of the page?

## HTML

```
<div class="magic-layout isotope">
    <div id="panel2" class="panel panel-default magic-element isotope-item">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="panel-title">Additional</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="role[]" placeholder="Role" class="form-control" display="text" /> 
                <input type="text" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  display="text"/>

                <input type="text" name="last_name[]" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  display="text"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone[]" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" display="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="address_line_1[]" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control"  display="text"/>
                <input type="text" name="address_line_2[]" placeholder="Address Line 2" class="form-control"  display="text" value=""/>
                <input type="text" name="line_3[]" placeholder="City, State Zip" class="form-control"  display="text"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="contact_id[]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <additional></additional>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel panel-default magic-element isotope-item">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="addRow(this.form)">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum++;
    var row = '<div id="panel2" class="panel panel-default magic-element isotope-item"><div class="panel-heading"><span class="panel-title">Additional</span></div><div class="panel-body"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="role[]" placeholder="Role" class="form-control" display="text" /> <input type="text" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  display="text"/><input type="text" name="last_name[]" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  display="text"/><input type="text" name="phone[]" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" display="text" /></div><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="address_line_1[]" placeholder="Address Line 1" class="form-control"  display="text"/><input type="text" name="address_line_2[]" placeholder="Address Line 2" class="form-control"  display="text" value=""/><input type="text" name="line_3[]" placeholder="City, State Zip" class="form-control"  display="text"/><input type="hidden" name="contact_id[]" value=""></div></div></div>';
    $(row).insertAfter('additional');
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some code?

Comment: Most certainly. I will update the question.

Comment: There is no `<additional></additional>` valid HTML element.

Comment: Yeah I know I just wanted a marker where I could `insertAfter` with no effect on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the click event of your button wasn't bound to your function `addRow` correctly.

Instead of binding the event from `onclick="addRow(this.form)"`, try creating the click event as follows instead:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        addRow($(this));
    });
});
```

where `mybutton` is your **Add** button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block" id="mybutton">Add</button>
```

Here's a Fiddle including the changes made: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Littm/q7sVj/)

Have a try and let me know :)

Comment: Hmm it keeps giving me a `$ is not defined` error on the `$(function(){` line. I have jQuery included and as you can see I have used it a couple lines up. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in the header tag or at the end of the body tag?

Comment: Oh yeah at the end of the body tag I guess thats the problem.

Comment: I got your code to work but I am still having the same problem as before. Only that part of the page needs to reload after the section is added.